# iOS app crashes repeatedly after running for months

Tags: ios, exception, crash

I have a situation where an app that a customer has been running for months seems to get corrupted and now crashes every time. It seems like some sort of corruption, but I am stuck and looking for help.

The app is simple, basically just a web control pointing at a particular URL, and not much else in the app. It hasn't been changed or updated, but it has started having this issue on a handful of the devices they run it on.

The error:

> Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP) Exception Codes:
>   0x0000000000000001, 0x00000000e7ffdefe Triggered by Thread:  0
>
> Dyld Error Message:   Library not loaded: @executable_path/a.dylib
>   Referenced from:
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/C3D711A3-5798-4EB6-A7DB-CEF49BA721CD/Hybridizer.app/Hybridizer
>   Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
>     /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/C3D711A3-5798-4EB6-A7DB-CEF49BA721CD/Hybridizer.app/a.dylib:
>   mmap() error 1 at address=0x00138000, size=0x00056000 segment=__TEXT
>   in Segment::map() mapping
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/C3D711A3-5798-4EB6-A7DB-CEF49BA721CD/Hybridizer.app/a.dylib
>     /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/C3D711A3-5798-4EB6-A7DB-CEF49BA721CD/Hybridizer.app/a.dylib:
>   mmap() error 1 at address=0x001FD000, size=0x00056000 segment=__TEXT
>   in Segment::map() mapping
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/C3D711A3-5798-4EB6-A7DB-CEF49BA721CD/Hybridizer.app/a.dylib
>   Dyld Version: 353.9
>
> Binary Images: 0x1fe60000 - 0x1fe83fff dyld armv7 
>   <4e5bac66e3d137b9aa8b1f5ee2cadd0b> /usr/lib/dyld 0x2b2f2000 -
>   0x2b622fff CoreFoundation armv7  <8903e0338b7a3055a6da8d09d9dd819c>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
>   0x2b623000 - 0x2b74cfff CoreGraphics armv7 
>   <3ece7760b9ad3e7fa1b33befa649bf97>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
>   0x2c03d000 - 0x2c23ffff Foundation armv7 
>   <03e4284e97fc3400945658d056252397>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation 0x2e890000
>   - 0x2f133fff UIKit armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit 0x38657000 -
>   0x38658fff libSystem.B.dylib armv7  
>   /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib 0x390be000 - 0x392b8fff libobjc.A.dylib
>   armv7   /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib

It is complaining that it can't find `a.dylib`, which is not a valid `dylib`. I have used `otool` and `MachOView` to examine the binary and it links only with the libraries listed in the crash log. It does use `libobjc.A.dylib`, so I am wondering if somehow the dynamic load table got corrupted? Is this possible and has anyone seen it?

I have searched for similar issues but only found legitimate cases of exception `0x00000000e7ffdefe`, where the dylib is truly missing. I haven't seen anyone report this, where all of a sudden it is looking for a dylib that really doesn't exist.

Reinstalling the app fixes the problem. The customer runs it on a lot of iPads at kiosks, so updating them is difficult.

I'd appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: I don't see why this was downvoted as it is well phrased with plenty of information.  That `a.dylib` is clearly in the app bundle as the dynamic linker finds it, but cannot load it.  But you say it's not in the app bundle you submit to Apple?

Comment: It is an enterprise signed app, not submitted to the app store. I've rebuilt the code to verify it, and there is no a.dylib in there.

Comment: So my mistake, turns out we do inject another dylib after the build is done, and it is called a.dylib. However, the question still stands - the app runs for months, then starts failing, and the device has not been altered. Has anyone seen similar behavior?